# Copy Files Names from a Folder as single File Name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement as ADLS container contains a folder with multiple files
Assume

1. Product.csv
2. Market.csv
   3.Sales.csv

I need to consider file names Product, Market, Sales and form as Product_Market_Sales.csv in a destination path.

I tried multiple ways to achieve this.
Can anyone help me.

Thanks
Shanu

Comment: Hey, Are the schema of all files the same?

Comment: If I can understand correctly. You want merge three csv files into one. Then you have to some code to do that. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-merge-large-csv-files-into-a-single-file-with-python-c66696f595ff

Answer (score 0):

**If all of your files are having same schema**, then the below approach will work for you.

These are my variables in the pipeline.

[image]

- First use Get Meta data activity to get the `ChildItems` list from the folder.

  It will give the array like below in an alphabetical order of file names.

  [image]
- Then, Give this array to a ForEach activity. Inside ForEach, split each file name with `'.'` or `'.c'` and store the first element of split in an append variable activity to `res_filename` variable using below dynamic content.

  `@split(item().name,'.')[0]`
- Now, join this array with `'_'` and store it in a string variable.
  `@concat(join(variables('names'),'_'),'.csv')`

  [image]
- After this, use copy activity and give wild card path `*.csv` in the source. Use dataset parameters for the sink dataset and give the above variable as file name and give the **Copy behavior** as `Merge files`.

**This is my Pipeline JSON**

```
{
"name": "filenames",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Get Metadata1",
            "type": "GetMetadata",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "Sourcefiles",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "fieldList": [
                    "childItems"
                ],
                "storeSettings": {
                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                },
                "formatSettings": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "names",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@split(item().name,'.')[0]",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "ForEach1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "res_filename",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@concat(join(variables('names'),'_'),'.csv')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Copy data1",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "wildcardFileName": "*.csv",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                        "quoteAllText": true,
                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Sourcefiles",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "target",
                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                    "parameters": {
                        "targetfilename": {
                            "value": "@variables('res_filename')",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "names": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "res_filename": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

**Result file:**

[image]

**If you want to merge the above with different source schemas**, then as per my knowledge its better do that by code as suggested in comments with databricks or Azure functions.